# how can I split strings within a list into individual characters?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that contains strings within it. I want to access and print each letter within that string.

```
list = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
```

I want to print the following:

```
['T', 'h', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k']...
```

I have tried:

```
list2 = list(list1)
print(list2)
```

I would also like to know how to get the index of each letter, so first letter has index1, second letter has index2 and so on.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
>>> [letter for word in a for letter in word]
['T', 'h', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'x']
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a string into a list of chars, use `list(string)` is the way, but here before that, you need to join the words into one unique string

```
values = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
res = list("".join(values))
print(res)  # ['T', 'h', 'e', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'x']
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted. It's the only correct answer in this thread, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
malist = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
new =[letter for i in malist for letter in i ]
print(new)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this

```
list_of_word = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"]

output = []
for word in list_of_word:
    for letter in word:
        output.append(letter)
print(output)
```

Comment: Don't name the list `list`, that is python keyword :)